# When div blurs check for content change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set up some content editable divs that have onblur functionality

```
<div class="inline-edit" contenteditable="true"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.inline-edit').blur(function()
{
  //functionality
});
});
```

and that all works grand for the functionality I've set up.

However the problem is the functionality will always occur when the blur even fires, even if the content in the editable div is never changed!

As the onchange method only works for inputs/textareas etc
I was curious if there was a simple~ way to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.inline-edit').blur(function()
{
  if($('div.inline-edit').contentChanged())
  {
     //functionality
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also look for `keypress` inside the `div`.

```
var changed = false;

$('#your-div').keypress(function (){
    changed = true;
});
```

Or if your div data is very simple, you could save the original content and compare it when needed.

Comment: sorry it took so long to actually accept an answer. This worked for what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If only using 1 div, I'd set up an old and new variable and compare them on blur.

```
$(document).ready( () => {
  var oldVal = $('.inline-edit').val();

  $('.inline-edit').blur( () => {
    let newVal = $('.inline-edit').val();

    if (newVal === oldVal) {
      return
    }

    //functionality
  });

});
```